# How to handle message queue failure in windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq

I have a windows service which generally takes message from msmq of another server.

It works most of the time but once in a month it throws below error:

The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

```
Exception Message: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
 Stack Trace:    at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, Boolean throwException)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_FormatName()
```

Or sometimes:

```
Exception Message: 
 Stack Trace:    at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
```

So it is random and only solution is to restart service manually.

And for message queue exception we are throwing the exception, that is why only solution to run application is by manually restarting the service.

I am thinking to let application retry for 5 times and then do something like restart if it fails continuously.

I have tried below code but when it stops, it obviously will not come back to below code to start it again as service itself trying to restart.

```
catch (MessageQueueException e)
                        {
                            if (e.MessageQueueErrorCode != MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)
                            {
                                // Very unusual
                                LogWrapper.WriteErrorLog(e, "MessageQueueException occuring for the following machine: " + queue.MachineName + " and the following queue: " + queue.QueueName, false, DateTime.Now);

                                // Restart service if it fails for more than 5 times
                                if (maxTries == 0)
                                {
                                    var service = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(serviceName);
                                    service.Stop();
                                    //service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

                                    LogWrapper.WriteErrorLog(e, "Restarting service as it reached maximum retry count for exception: " + e.Message, false, DateTime.Now);
                                    service.Start();
                                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                                    //Environment.Exit(1);
                                }

                                maxTries--;
                                //throw;
                            }
```

What should be the best solution in this case?

Comment: do you control how the service is installed? maybe you could just crash current process and let windows restart the service for you if you set it up to restart on failure (e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/48600/how-can-i-automatically-restart-a-windows-service-if-it-crashes)

Comment: MQ is supposed to be able to deal with mishaps like this.  But can't when the queue lives on another machine and that machine, or the network, gets wonky.  Consider using a private queue instead.

Comment: @slawekwin: You mean like this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662(v=ws.11).aspx and also is it good practice?

Comment: Okay @HansPassant, You meant private queue in remote machine right? so how private queues will not behave like this?

Comment: No, private queue on the machine that generates these errors.  It can't disappear, not without considerable amounts of smoke anyway.

Comment: But I can not make that changes, consider I have to deal with what I have then can you suggest the best approach @HansPassant?

Comment: I don't see how this would be worse practice than restarting manually. This is why they include such feature for services, but you might want to log restarts heavily to diagnose other potential issues

Comment: If you cannot change it then don't make it your problem.  A flakey production machine or network is not a programmer's problem, that's a job for IT staff.  Whomever has the authority to do something about it can easily fix it.  Including the config changes that @slawekin talks about.  Just make sure your program crashes and burns when it happens.

Comment: Okay thanks @HansPassant, One question, if I go with what slawekin is suggesting then will it work in case of failover cluster? As our service is having failover cluster.